# Make 5 5 5 5 = 19

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory

Can you find a way to make:

> $5\ 5 \ 5 \ 5 = 19$

by adding any operations or symbols? You can use only these symbols:

> $+,\ -,\ *,\ !,\ /,\ \hat\, ,\ ()$.

It is limited to this list, and concatenation is also allowed. You cannot add other numbers to the equation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82373/discussion-on-question-by-kraby15-make-5-5-5-5-19). If you have legitimate questions about the puzzle statement, including allowed operations and the like, ask them (to the OP) or include your assumptions in your answer as others have done; debating them with other users is a fairly fruitless exercise, and *not what comments are for* in any case.

Comment: The amount of solutions is likely to be too big. I am not sure if answers putting operations between 1 and 9 are valid. BTW, came up with different solution which is, I guess, uninteresting (because there already are too many) and anyway I can't post an answer.

Comment: There are lots of possible solutions for this question. A lot of good answers have been given too. It would be nice if one got accepted and the question closed or else it feels like it is too broad with a lot of correct answers.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's one way I found:

> $\dfrac{5!-(5\times 5)}{5}=19$

Or, using just the characters explicitly allowed in the question:

> `(5! - (5 * 5)) / 5 = 19`

Comment: Somebody upvote once more (I already have)! It's a great answer and @Riley's nearly on $10k$ reputation! :D

Comment: @user477343 Thank you! I will now use my powers responsibly.

Comment: Well, after those Riley riddles you made, I think you quite deserve it :)

Answer (score 37):

If the [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) is allowed, then I propose

> $$5!!+5-5/5$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5!!%2B5-5%2F5) agrees that the result is 19.

Answer (score 31):

I am quite sure it is not the expected answer but it is the immediate answer comes into my mind.

> $\frac{5+5}{5+5}=1^9$

Comment: I like this one (+1), as my immediate answer (with fewer symbols) would be similar, alternating division and multiplication, while keeping the same right-hand side as yours. (Meta: I'm not writing my solution in the comment in order to avoid spoiling, as rot13 wouldn't work here. Not sure what is the standard policy in this case. Should I post it as a separate answer?)

Comment: @Maiaux if it is really similar, do not post it as a seperate answer. This has happened before [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70684/make-5-5-5-5-19), where a user deleted his/her answer (I won't name who, exactly) for its similarity compared to another answer.

Answer (score 27):

For the 5s

> $$\left(5 - \frac55\right)! - 5 = 19 $$

For the 1s (previous edit)

> $$(1+1+1)!-1=5$$

Answer (score 18):

My way:

> $(5+5)\times\frac55=1+9$

and

> $(5+5)-\frac55=1\times9$

New, and added for it's simplicity:

> $5+5+5-5=1+9$

Answer (score 16):

In base-11, the trivial addition works:

> $$ 5_{11} + 5_{11} + 5_{11} + 5_{11} = 19_{11} $$

Comment: Those subscript 1s could be considered other numbers?

Comment: just remove the subscripts they are not needed (can we not as usual ignore the number base).

Answer (score 13):

> 5555 != 19 : Credit :  Jonathan Allan

Comment: Is this now an equation?

Answer (score 3):

From [the comment above](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70684/10525#comment211536_70684)

> 5555 ≠ 19

Answer (score 3):

One way to think of it -

> 19 HEX = 25 DEC

Therefore -

> $\frac{ 5 }{ 5 } * 5 * 5 = 25$

Answer (score 1):

> (5! - 5 * 5) / 5 = 19
>  (120 - 25) / 5 = 19
>  95 / 5 = 19

or

> 5 + 5 + 5 - 5 = 1 + 9