# Make 6 5 4 3 = 1

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory

Can you find a way to make:

> 6 5 4 3 = 1

by concatenation and/or adding any of (and only) these mathematical operators:

- +
- -
- ×
- !
- ÷
- ^
- standard parentheses ()

You cannot add other numbers to the equation.
The result must be a mathematical equality.

---

Inspired by [Make 5 5 5 5 = 19](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70684/16717)

Comment: Yep, I totally failed to see the obvious! Hopefully [6 5 4 3 = 81](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70712/16717) will be more fun.

Comment: Chill Everyone! Stop Downvoting Just Becasue it's obvious +1

Comment: I can do $6\; 5 \;4\; 3\; 2 = 1$ by how $4!\div (6\times (5-3)\times 2) = 1$ :D

Comment: I can also complete it without the $6$ by how $(4!-3!)\div 5!! = 1$ :D

Answer (score 10):

One possible answer is:

> (6 - 5) * (4 - 3)

By request another:

> -(6 + 5) + (4 * 3)

Some tongue in cheek answers:

> (6 - 5)! * (4 - 3)! 
>  (6 - 5) ^ (4 - 3) 
>  (6 - 5) / (4 - 3) 
>  (6 - 5)! / (4 -3)! 
>  plus other combinations of factorials of 1

Another solution:

> 6 + 5 - 4 - 3!

More complicated:

> (6!) / (5 * 4! * 3!)

Comment: Nice and simple one... any more? :)

Comment: Ho hum. I epic fail :D guess I'll try again...

Comment: Should I go on?

Comment: LOL, see my previous comment

Comment: @wolfram42 Yes, please go on [there](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70838/32339) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to try:

> $$\dfrac{-6+5+4}{3}=1$$

and:

> $$\dfrac{6\times5}{4!+3!}=1$$

Answer (score 4):

The simplest:

> $65 - 4^3$

(I wrote a program.)

Answer (score 1):

Some exponential solutions

> $\frac{6^{5-4}}{3!} $
>  $(6 - 5^{4-3})$

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution

> ${3 - \dfrac{6 + 4}{5}}$

In code form

> `3 - (6 + 4)/5`

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.

> (6-5)*4-3
>  6-5=1   => 1*4=4  => 4-3=**1**

Cannot get simpler than this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE! Please hide your answers in spoilers using the >! prefix on the lines needing hiding.

Comment: sure will do from now.. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions I found:

> - (6-5)^(4-3)
>
>   (6-5)*(4-3)
>
>   (6-5)/(4-3)
>
>   (6+5)-(4+3!)
>
>   (6+5)+(4*3)
>
> ... way too many!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PSE! Unfortunately your answer doesn't add anything new to the existng ones (wolfram42 already gave the same answers like you did). Anyways, feel free to stick around, check out [the Tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and enjoy your stay at the site!

Answer (score 1):

Simple and in order:

> (6 - 5 - 4 + 3)!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the following is possible:

> (6+5)->(11)->(1+1)

then: 
1)

> ((6+5)-4)+3)=1

2)

> ((11)-(4)+3)=1

3)

> ((1+1)-(4)+3)=1

4)

> (2-4)+3=1

Here is another one:

> ((6*5)-4!)/3!