# Maximize the number of factorials in your solution to 6 5 4 3 = 1

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory

Using the same rules as [Make 6 5 4 3 = 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/make-6-5-4-3-1), but maximize the number of factorials.  You may not take the factorial of 1 or 2.

This is harder than it looks.  A great answer has six factorials, an amazing answer has seven factorials, and an outstanding answer has eight or more factorials.

Edit: Shoot, I should have blocked factorials of numbers bigger than twenty like I did in my program.

Comment: I'm guessing we shouldn't take the factorial of 2 either

Comment: Is the answer really different than [wolfram42's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70711/32339) to the other puzzle? (3 factorials)

Comment: @xhienne That was my opinion but if he found 8 that is probably precise enough for another question.

Comment: @xhienne I found a solution with eight factorials.  There are 72 solutions with four or more factorials.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see those edits. Wow, 8 factorials, that's interesting!

Comment: @NeilG Is the rule on the factorial of 2 really useful? Since 2 isn't in the authorized digits.

Comment: @Saeïdryl I understand that you can not use (6 - 5)! nor (6 - 4)!

Comment: @Saeïdryl Great question.  In fact, yes it does matter!  You are able to achieve an unbounded number of factorials without this rule, but if I tell you how I reveal too much about the problem.

Comment: Are double factorials allowed, and if so, how do you count them?

Comment: @aschepler I didn't consider them as one of the allowed operations given the other question.  (I would imagine if they were allowed, they would have their own entry in the list.)

Comment: @NeilG Double factorial is certainly a different operation from the listed operations. But as a devil's advocate, it says concatenation is allowed, and doesn't specify that means concatenation of digits, so concatenating two "!" gives the different operation "!!".

Comment: @aschepler Fair enough!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll attempt with the rule "No factorials on numbers greater than 20". Here is a solution with 7. Some formatting help is appreciated

> $$\frac{6!}{(5!\div4!)!}! \div 3!!$$

Method:

> I started with the observation that 6! / 5! = 6, Likewise 5!/4! = 5. 3! = 6 so 6! = 3!! I then built up from there. So 6! = (6!/(5! / 4!))!

Figured out the missing factorial:

> $$\left(\frac{6!}{(5!\div4!)!}! - 3!!\right)!$$ works since 0! = 1 by definition.

Comment: Missing one pair of parentheses I think, but yes amazing!  How did you do it?

Comment: Actually i made a quick edit and I confused myself. I'll readjust in a minute

Comment: Nice, you're pretty close to 8

Comment: @NeilG I think I got it this time

Comment: Presumably by $n!!$ you mean $(n!)!$, not the *double factorial* operation $\prod_{k \in \mathbb N, n - 2 k > 0} (n - 2 k)$?

Comment: I assumed that the double factorial operation was not allowed since it would be easy to get more than 8 that way.

Comment: You should write the factorial of 3! as (3!)!.

Answer (score 43):

The answer is

> Infinite factorials even without factorials of 1 or 2. By this equation  $$6!!!\ldots * (5-4) \div 3!!!!\ldots = 1$$
>  Notice that the 3 has one more factorial. This comes from the fact that $3!=6$ and we can keep adding factorials to both.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant

Comment: (I know this is the best answer, but I hope you don't mind that I marked the other answer as accepted since it was the one I was shooting for.)

Comment: @NeilG Unless this was secretly a riddle, you should accept the best possible answer.  It turns out that one of the responders was more clever than you - reward that!

Comment: @jeremy well I upvoted him ?

Answer (score 12):

How about

> Infinitely many factorials?
>  A basic example would be : $\frac{6 * (5-4)}{  3!} = 1$
>  But you could add some factorials in the lot : $\frac{6! * (5-4) }{ 3!!} = 1 $ 
>  Or even : $\frac{6!!!!!!!\times  (5-4) }{ (3!)!!!!!!!} = 1  $
>  Really, as long as there is one more factorial behind the 3, we're good!

Comment: Damn you, @Bennett Bernardoni ! :p

Comment: Great answer! And congratz on the $7k$ rep! :D

Answer (score 6):

Starting from [wolfram42's answer to that other puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70711/32339), the maximum number of factorials is:

> infinite since you can add any equal number of `!` to the numerator and denominator of
>  `(6!) / (5 * 4! * 3!)`
>
>   Well, since I'm no mathematician, I may say "infinite plus three" actually ;-)

Note: that's also true for any answer to the other puzzle that involved a division, like [JonMark Perry's two solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70718/32339)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the general programming solution to these kinds of problems.  It also prints out for every result, how many solutions there are, which is useful in coming up with these kinds of problem:

```
from enum import IntEnum
from fractions import Fraction
from memoized import memoized
import math


NUMBERS = [6, 5, 4, 3]
RESULT = Fraction(1)


class Levels(IntEnum):
    ADDITION = 0
    MULTIPLICATION = 1
    NEGATION = 2
    POWER = 3
    FACTORIAL = 4
    BARE = 5


class Result:

    def __init__(self, value, way, level):
        """
        * value is the value achieved.
        * way is string representation of an expression.
        * level is the outermost operator applied to the expression, which
          determines how this expression should be braketed when it's part of a
          larger expression.
        """
        assert isinstance(value, Fraction)
        assert isinstance(level, Levels)
        self.value = value
        self.way = way
        self.level = level

    def bracketed(self, for_level):
        if for_level > self.level:
            return f"({self.way})"
        return self.way


def combine(left_rs, right_rs):
    for l in left_rs:
        for r in right_rs:
            if r.level not in (Levels.NEGATION, Levels.ADDITION):
                # We block a - (-b), and a + (-b) since these can be written as
                # a + b, and a - b.  We also block a + (b + c), and a - (b + c)
                # since these can be written as a + b + c, and a - b - c.
                yield Result(l.value + r.value,
                             f"{l.bracketed(Levels.ADDITION)} + {r.bracketed(Levels.ADDITION + 1)}",
                             Levels.ADDITION)
                yield Result(l.value - r.value,
                             f"{l.bracketed(Levels.ADDITION)} - {r.bracketed(Levels.ADDITION + 1)}",
                             Levels.ADDITION)
            if r.level != Levels.MULTIPLICATION:
                # We block a * (b * c) since this can be written as a * b * c.
                # We block a * (b / c) since this can be written as a * b / c.
                yield Result(l.value * r.value,
                             f"{l.bracketed(Levels.MULTIPLICATION)} * {r.bracketed(Levels.MULTIPLICATION + 1)}",
                             Levels.MULTIPLICATION)
            if r.value != 0 and (r.level != Levels.MULTIPLICATION):
                # We block a / (b / c) since this can be written as a / b * c.
                # We block a / (b * c) since this can be written as a / b / c.
                yield Result(l.value / r.value,
                             f"{l.bracketed(Levels.MULTIPLICATION)} / {r.bracketed(Levels.MULTIPLICATION + 1)}",
                             Levels.MULTIPLICATION)
            new_value = None
            power_okay = l.value >= 0 or r.value.denominator % 2 == 1
            if l.value == 1:
                new_value = Fraction(1)
            elif l.value == -1:
                if power_okay:
                    new_value = Fraction(-1
                                         if r.value.numerator % 2 == 1
                                         else 1)
            elif l.value == 0:
                if r.value > 0:
                    new_value = Fraction(0)
            else:
                # Only whole number powers are allowed for numbers other than
                # -1, 0, 1.
                if (power_okay
                        and r.value.denominator == 1
                        and -8 < r.value.numerator < 8):
                    new_value = l.value ** r.value
            if new_value is not None:
                # The left side is bracketed when it's a power because power is
                # right associative.
                yield Result(new_value,
                             f"{l.bracketed(Levels.POWER + 1)} ^ {r.bracketed(Levels.POWER)}",
                             Levels.POWER)
            if (l.level == Levels.BARE
                    and r.level == Levels.BARE and len(r.way) == 1):
                # We concatenate 123 as 1(23), but not as (12)3.
                yield Result(l.value * 10 + r.value,
                             f"{l.way}{r.way}",
                             Levels.BARE)


def negate(rs):
    for r in rs:
        yield r
        if r.level > Levels.MULTIPLICATION:
            # We block -(a + b) since this can be written -a - b.
            # We block -(a - b) since this can be written -a + b.
            # We block -(a * b) since this can be written -a * b.
            # We block -(a / b) since this can be written -a / b.
            yield Result(-r.value,
                         f"-{r.bracketed(Levels.NEGATION)}",
                         Levels.NEGATION)


def factorialize(rs):
    for r in rs:
        yield r
        x = 0
        while (r.value.denominator == 1
               and (r.value.numerator == 0 or (3 <= r.value.numerator <= 20))):
            # We block fractional and negative factorials.
            # We block 1 and 2 factorial.
            # We block gigantic factorials.
            r = Result(Fraction(math.factorial(r.value.numerator)),
                       f"{r.bracketed(Levels.FACTORIAL + 1)}!",
                       Levels.FACTORIAL)
            yield r


# memoization makes the recursive solution into a dynamic programming solution.
@memoized(hashable=False)
def do(digits):
    """
    Given a list of digits, produce a list of Result objects.
    """
    l = len(digits)
    if l == 1:
        # Return a Result object for a single digit.
        new_rs = [Result(Fraction(digits[0]), str(digits[0]), Levels.BARE)]
    else:
        # The list of results for a list of digits is the total results for every contiguous partition.
        new_rs = []
        for i in range(1, l):
            new_rs.extend(list(combine(do(digits[:i]),
                                       do(digits[i:]))))
    return list(factorialize(negate(new_rs)))


rs = do(NUMBERS)
vs = {}
for r in rs:
    vs.setdefault(r.value, []).append(r)
print(f"Solutions to {NUMBERS} = {RESULT}")
for r in sorted(vs[RESULT], key=lambda r: len(r.way)):
    print(r.way)
print()
print(f"                         value solutions")
for v, l in sorted(vs.items(), key=lambda vl: (len(vl[1]), len(str(vl[0])))):
    print(f"{str(v):>30} {len(l):<12}")
```

prints

```
Solutions to [6, 5, 4, 3] = 1
65 - 4 ^ 3
(6 - 5) ^ 43
65 + (-4) ^ 3
-(-6 + 5) ^ 43
-6 - 5 + 4 * 3
6 + 5 - 4 - 3!
6 - 5 * (4 - 3)
6 - 5 / (4 - 3)
6 - 5 ^ (4 - 3)
6 / (5 + 4 - 3)
6 - 5! / 4 / 3!
(6 - 5) ^ 4 ^ 3
(6 - 5) ^ (-43)
...
(((-6 + 5 + 4)!)! - (3!)!)!
((6! / (5! / 4!)!)! - (3!)!)!
((-(-6) ^ (5 - 4))! - (3!)!)!
```

Comment: This code just bounced off my head. It would be great if will add some explanations in comments.

Comment: So what does this output?

Comment: @aschepler Added

Comment: @haccks I added some comments.

Answer (score 1):

## 9 factorials, following the rules (answer below)

### Some tricks to use

First trick:

> $0!=1$ ([by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#0!)). We will use the fact that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:0\cdot x=0 \Rightarrow (0\cdot x)!=1$.

Second trick:

> Since we cannot use $1!$ or $2!$ and we cannot use $n!$ for $n>20$, we have to look the other way: **think smaller**. [Lucky for us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial_of_a_non-integer), we have $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$ where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) and this holds for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

### Building our answer

First step (using the first trick):

> We need zero. That's pretty easy, we have $6!-(3!)!=6!-6!=0$.

Second step (using the second trick):

> We need many factorials but we can only use $4$ and $5$ because we used the others in the first step. To get those, we aren't going to worry about the outcome because we will multiply by $0$ anyway. We only have to be careful not to get to close to $0$ or $1$ (we shall stay at least $0.01$ distance away from them) and not to exceed $20$.

Calculations in the second step:

> The [first factorial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-5%2F4)!) $\left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)!\approx -4.9$.
>  The [second factorial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((-5%2F4)!)!) $\left(\left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)!\right)!\approx 0.50$.
>  The [third factorial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((-5%2F4)!)!)!) $\left(\left(\left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)!\right)!\right)!\approx 0.89$.
>  The [fourth factorial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((((-5%2F4)!)!)!)!) $\left(\left(\left(\left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\approx 0.96$.
>  The [fifth factorial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((((-5%2F4)!)!)!)!)!) $\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\approx 0.983$.
>  The [sixth factorial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((((((-5%2F4)!)!)!)!)!)!) $\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\approx 0.993$.
>  Therefore, we can use 5 factorials here, because with the sixth step we get to close to $1$.

### Answer

> $$x=6!-(3!)!=0$$
>  $$y=\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\frac{-5}{4}\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\approx 0.983$$
>  $$\textit{final answer}=(x\cdot y)!=0!=1$$