# Make 6 5 4 3 = 81

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory

Can you find a way to make:

> 6 5 4 3 = 81

by concatenation and/or adding any of (and only) these mathematical operators:

- +
- -
- ×
- !
- ÷
- ^
- standard parentheses ()

You cannot add other numbers to the equation, or re-order the existing numbers.
The result must be a mathematical equality.

#### Harder version...

Try to do it while only altering the left hand side!

---

Inspired by [Make 5 5 5 5 = 19](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/70684/16717)

Hopefully somewhat more challenging than my previous attempt (may be hard not to be!)

Comment: So $(6-5)\times 3^4=81$ won't work because I rearranged $3$ and $4$; and $6+\left(3\times 5^{\sqrt{4}}\right)=81$ won't work because there is at least a square root, right?

Comment: @user477343 correct on both accounts

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I thought a bit too much but I finally got it:

> $\frac{6+5!*4}{3!}=81$

Comment: Nice! Well done!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Very good.

Comment: Anyone looking for more to find, I have found another solution keeping the right hand side intact :)

Answer (score 29):

My solution: Just normal Math

> $-6 + (5 + 4!) \times 3 = 81$

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Looks like the simplest solution to the harder version so far.

Comment: Why is this in the low-quality queue? It looks like a perfectly acceptable answer to me. Welcome to the site, btw!

Comment: @F1Krazy iirc low quality queue is automatic, based on length of answer(and probably being a new user factors in)

Comment: This is the simplest answer according to my computer solution.

Answer (score 14):

Using the notation of [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html):

> $$6!!+5!!+4!-3! = (6\times4\times2)+(5\times3\times1)+(4\times3\times2\times1)-(3\times2\times1)$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6!!%2B5!!%2B4!-3!) approves it.

Comment: Nice! I did not see this one (maybe write out the way it evaluates since the double factorial operation is slightly lesser known (I see you linked to mathworld, but you know nice to have the working).

Comment: I've edited as your suggestion

Comment: Wow! That's the best one!

Answer (score 10):

My answer was (before the no swapping rule)

> $(6+3) \times (5+4)= 9\times9=81$

Edit, after the no swapping rule

> Step 1: $ 6+5+4+3=8+1$

and then

> Step 2: $ 1+8=9$ (because in the previous statement lhs=18)

Finally, maintaining all the rules, this was also written before the harder version was mentioned):

> $(6-5)+(4+3)=8\times1$

or

> $(6-5)\times(4+3)=8-1$

Comment: Hmm I thought "by concatenation and/or adding ..." was clear, must not be - I shall add "no reordering". Nice way to think outside the box though +1

Comment: Oops XD. Will try again. Maybe

Comment: @JonathanAllan Can I do it in two steps or do I have to do it in one step ?

Comment: I don't understand. You can use parentheses...

Comment: @JonathanAllan check it now? I think I'm bending the rules again :P

Comment: I see what you mean. It's fun but not what I was thinking should be within the "rules". I have no problem with pushing those boundaries though :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan the last one should be satisfactory :3. Should I remove the unnecessary answers? Or keep them as it is?

Comment: Looks like it works... can you make 81 (I should have worded the question better!)

Comment: I know. I could make 83 but then I referred to the original question and was able to think of this solution

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple one (easy mode):

> $$ 6\times(5-4)+3 = 8+1$$

Answer (score 4):

My answer:

> As concatenation allowed: 
>  $46 + $$35$$ =81$

Comment: +1 since you answered before my edit to disallow re-ordering :)

Comment: Yeah noticed that;)

Comment: $(+1)$, but that rearranges order...

Comment: Thaks @user477343, actually OP edited the question after or when I was answering;)

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

> $ 6 - 5 = 1 $ 
>  $ 4 + 3 = 7$
>
>   $1 + 7 = 8 * 1$

Comment: For the simple version of the challenge that indeed works (it's also been posted by R.D). You can do the steps using parentheses "(...)+(...)=...". By the way spoiler text is achieved by prefixing a line with >! (newlines can be placed inside these by adding two spaces to to end of the line and placing another >! on the next line (I see you are a regular on SO so I imagine you'll figure it all out easily - Welcome to your active-life at Puzzling!)

Comment: I'll take  your tips in consideration next time.Thank you @jonathan

Comment: Also, write `$\times$` to generate $\times$ for multiplication; you could also write `$\ast$` to generate "$\ast$" with better formatting :)

Answer (score 3):

Long time reader, first time answer-er:

> By using some muscle to get the subtraction to be commutative, -(-(6 - (5-4)) - 3)=8^1

Answer (score 2):

This feels like stretching the rules a little bit

> 65 + 4^(--3) = 81

This assumes that

> the decrement operator -- (minus minus)

is allowed.

Comment: Wouldn't the operator in question need to come prior to the number?

Comment: Since I have paranthesis, it can be on either side.

Comment: I tested it with parentheses and it didn't do the operation until after execution as I expected. Is this just a software level thing, or is it the same in mathematics?

Comment: I might have been wrong. I'm not familiar with this operator in mathematics, that's why I said this might be a little stretch. I'll change it to the front.

Comment: In case someone wanted to stick to the programming style: `65 | 4 << --3 = 81`

Comment: @user27263 (if you return) - `|` and `<<` are not in the list of allowed operations.

Answer (score 2):

> $654 + 3 = 81$, as long as you do the calculation in base 82.

Explanation:

> $ 654 + 3 == 657 $ in base 10, subtract 1 gives 656, which is $ 8 * 82$

Comment: This is really doing the calculation in base ten and then evaluating the result as if it were written in base eighty-two. Doing the calculation `654 + 3` in base eighty-two would be: forty-thousand-seven-hundred-and-fifty-eight plus three

Answer (score 2):

By modifying both sides:

> 6-5+4+3 = 8 ÷ 1