# Make 4 4 4 4 = 30,31

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Follow up question to [Make 5 5 5 5 = 19](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70684/make-5-5-5-5-19)

---

Can you find a way to make:

> $4\ 4 \ 4 \ 4 = 30$

and

> $4\ 4 \ 4 \ 4 = 31$

by adding any operations or symbols on the left side of the equations? You can use only these symbols:

> $+,\ -,\ *,\ !,\ /,\ \hat\, ,\ ()$.

It is limited to this list, and concatenation is also allowed.

Comment: Is there any rule that we cannot change the rhs or touch it?

Comment: @R.D nope, it is limited with LHS

Comment: @Oray Can I reorder the numbers on the LHS?

Comment: @rhsquared they are all the same though

Comment: @R.D Doh! I can see that.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93729/how-many-fours-are-needed-to-represent-numbers-up-to-n?rq=1) might be helpful :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the first one

> $(4 + (4/4))!/4  = 30$

Second one

> $4! + (4!+4)/4 = 31$

Comment: it took too long! :)

Comment: Oof. Beat me to the second one by just one minute

Answer (score 9):

## Four Fours

**FIRST:**

1. > $\sqrt4 +\sqrt4 +\sqrt4 + 4!=30$

2. > $(4\times 4\times \sqrt{4}) -\sqrt{4} = 30$

3. > $((4\times 4!) + 4!)\div 4 = 30$

4. > $4! + \sqrt{4} + (4\div \sqrt{4}) = 30$

Really similar to 1:

> $4! - \sqrt{4}+4+4 = 30$

Really similar to 2:

> $(4^{\sqrt{4}}\times \sqrt{4})-\sqrt{4}= 30$

**SECOND:**

1. > $((4+\sqrt{4})!+4!)\div 4! = 31$

---

Solutions that bend the rules, slightly.

1. > $(4+4+4)\div .4 =30$

2. > $4!+\sqrt{4}+(\sqrt{4}\div .4) = 31$

---

Weird resemblance between these two other solutions!

> $\big(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}}^{\,4!} - 4\big)\div \sqrt{4}=30$

> $\big(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}}^{\,4!} - \sqrt4\big)\div \sqrt{4}=31$

$$$$

## Three Fours

**FIRST:**

> $(4!\div 4)+4!=30$

Comment: I think roots and log is not allowed here :P

Comment: @IanFako I forgot to read the most important part...

Comment: Wow those nested radicals are awesome

Comment: @sedrick technically that's an eighth root $\sqrt [8]{4}$ but I didn't write the eight.

Comment: Isn't $4! - \sqrt{4} + (4\div .4) = 32$? $(24) - (2) + (10)$

Comment: @JAD oh shucks... I miscalculated... my bad! Thanks for picking that up :0

Answer (score 7):

Another possible answer:

> $(4 - (4/4))! + 4! = 30$

A weird but fun stretch answer:

> If you concatenate $4/4$ and $4!$ that's $124$. 
>  $124 / 4 = 31$

Making $30$ with just three $4$'s:

> $\frac{(\frac{4!}{4})!}{4!} = 30$

Making $31$ with just three $4$'s (violates rules):

> $16$th root of $24!$ is $30.69$ so 
>  $\biggl \lceil \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}{4 * 4}]{(4!)!} \biggr \rceil = 31$

Since we're already violating lots of rules in the first place, we can make both $30$ and $31$ with JUST ONE $4$.

> $30 = \biggl\lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{(4!)!}}}} \biggr\rfloor$ 
>  $31 = \biggl\lceil \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{(4!)!}}}} \biggr\rceil$

Comment: That second answer is great! :D

Comment: I might have a crack at three fours :P

Comment: @user477343 Man we're taking these puzzles waaaay too seriously

Comment: Oh my... the last answer is a beast!!

Comment: I am also struggling to come up with a different three-fours solution for $31$...

Comment: So I got curious after finding that last answer and did some research. This is pretty interesting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48633/using-floor-ceiling-square-root-and-factorial-functions-to-get-integers It's apparently possible to start with a single 4 and end with any positive integer.

Comment: Hahah, that is amazing! I am going to bookmark that link :D

Comment: with JUST ONE 4 killed me. +1

Comment: Upvoted just for the ridiculous "one four" solution. I wonder if you can make an insane RISC computer capable of just these two arithmetic operations, and define all of mathematics in terms of them.

Answer (score 3):

The second one (with [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial))

> $4!! * 4 - (4/4)$

Comment: !! is different operator than !

Comment: He didn't mention double factorial though

Comment: "by adding **any** symbols", it's not prohibited according to the question

Comment: Up to OP to decide if it's right or wrong XD

Comment: Took this hint from the original `5 5 5 5 = 19` problem :D

Comment: Yes I saw that. But all subsequent puzzles that are of the same type have some restriction rule. Or else it will be the same puzzle lol.
There is nothing wrong with your answer though. It **may not** be allowed. Depends on the op

Comment: The question does impose limit on symbols, but clearly states "any operations".

Answer (score 3):

For the first one (Double factorial used)

> $(4! + 4 + \frac{4!!}{4}) = 30$

For the second one (Double factorial again):

> $(4! + 4!! - \frac{4 }{ 4}) = 31$

Answer (score 1):

For 30:

> $(!4 - 4) \times \left( \frac{4!}{4} \right)$
>
>  $ =(9 - 4) \times \left( \frac{24}{4} \right) = 5 \times 6 = 30$

For 31:

> $44 - 4 - !4$
>
>  $= 44 - 4 - 9 = 31$

Note that:

> $!n$ is the subfactorial of $n$.
>  For a non-negative-integer $n$ this is the number of **[derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)** of $n$
>  (the number of ways to arrange $n$ items such that *no* item is at its naturally ordered position)
>  This is
>  $n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$
>
>  As such
>  $!4 = 4! \sum_{i=0}^4 \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} = 24 \times \left(\frac{(-1)^0}{0!} + \frac{(-1)^1}{1!} + \frac{(-1)^2}{2!} + \frac{(-1)^3}{3!} + \frac{(-1)^4}{4!}\right)$
>  $= 24 \times \left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{-1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-1}{6} + \frac{1}{24}\right)$
>  $= \left(24 - 24 + 12 - 4 + 1\right)$
>  $= 9$
>
>  Or, using ABCD, the 9 derangements are:
>  1. BADC
>  2. BCDA
>  3. BDAC
>  4. CADB
>  5. CDAB
>  6. CDBA
>  7. DABC
>  8. DCAB
>  9. DCBA
>
>  But not any of the other 15 permutations:
>  **ABCD** . **A**CDB . BA**C**D . CAB**D** . DA**C**B
>  **AB**DC . **A**DBC . BCA**D** . C**B**A**D** . D**B**AC
>  **A**CB**D** . **A**D**C**B . BD**C**A . C**B**DA . D**BC**A

Answer (score 0):

How About

> 4444 != 31

and

> 4444 != 30

Reason

> != means not equal to in many (programming) languages